# He is man enough versus it's word enough

Tags: nouns

He is man enough to work there.

I think the sentence is correct. What if we substitute man for word?

> It is word enough for me.

> It is word enough to merit research.

Are the two sentences with WORD correct?

Comment: We would only say "word enough" in extremely unusual contexts. What are you trying to say?

Comment: It is word enough to merit research. I mean that this is a word worth doing research on.

Comment: If by *word* you mean a verbal expression, it would more likely be said "It's enough of a word..."  Even then, it's an odd thing to say about a word. If by *word*, you mean information or a report, it would still be a strange expession.

Comment: If by word I mean a word?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.lexico.com/definition/word) "word" has several meanings. For example it might mean communication; news. For example, "I have received word from France..." That's why Mr O'Flaherty and I asked you to explain what you meant.

Comment: ... I think the answer is no: you can't use it like that. "Man enough" is almost unvarying enough to be called a set phrase. We often say "<adjective> enough" or "<adverb> enough", but there are few examples of "<noun> enough." We say "Room enough", "space enough" "time enough" and "life enough" - all _abstract_ nouns -, but not, for example, "woman/horse/house enough." Even "We had seas/fields/woods enough" would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't work at all.

You might (rarely) use "man enough" because there are (perceived) degrees of manliness. Since men are (supposed) to be strong and tough, the phrase "He is man enough to ..." means "He is strong and tough enough".  There's no problem with this second expression, because "strong" and "tough" are adjectives and have degrees (strong - stronger - very strong etc).

But there is no metaphorical notion of degrees of wordness.  The word "cat" is a word. The word "inexpensive" is a word.  But neither one is "more word" than the other! And even if you decide that "cat" has more wordness than "inexpensive", that is not a reason to do research on it.

You do research on a word, not because it is "very word", but because it is very interesting.

> It is an interesting enough word to merit research.

<sub>I can think of some *very* strained cases:  *"the possessive clitic "'s" is not considered a proper word by some people, but it is word enough for me!"*  Here there is a deliberate jocular use of the expression.  It's not a  good example of natural English.</sub>